Issues Processing a Large CSV File from S3 in Java
I am trying to retrieve and process a large CSV file (130,000 KB) from Amazon S3, but the processing takes over an hour, and at a certain point, an error occurs.
The code I use to retrieve the file is as follows:
   try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(s3ServiceStock.getObject(key).getObjectContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
              CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(reader).withCSVParser(parser).build()) {

         importContent(csvReader )

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error", e);
        }
}


The importContent method looks like this:
private void importContent(CSVReader csvReader) throws IOException {

        String[] nextRecord;
        while ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {

          ...//some treatment

         repository.save(entity);
       }

}


However, at some point during the process, I encounter the following error, which seems to occur on different lines of the CSV file:
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 130,272,542; received: 22,061,056)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:178) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135) ~[httpclient-4.5.9.jar:4.5.9]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.604.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:180) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.604.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.604.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.604.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.604.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:180) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.604.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.604.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.util.LengthCheckInputStream.read(LengthCheckInputStream.java:107) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.604.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.604.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3AbortableInputStream.read(S3AbortableInputStream.java:125) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.604.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.604.jar:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:181) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:326) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:392) ~[na:na]
    at com.opencsv.stream.reader.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:41) ~[opencsv-4.6.jar:na]
    at com.opencsv.CSVReader.getNextLine(CSVReader.java:436) ~[opencsv-4.6.jar:na]
    at com.opencsv.CSVReader.readNext(CSVReader.java:351) ~[opencsv-4.6.jar:na]
    at ...
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]

This error points to the line where ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) { is called in the importContent method.
I thought the issue might be that maintaining the connection to the S3 repository for such a long time was causing the error. Therefore, I tried using TransferManager to download the file:
@Override
    public void downloadFileWithTransferManager(String key, String downloadFilePath){
        TransferManager transferManager = TransferManagerBuilder.standard()
                .withS3Client(s3)
                .withExecutorFactory(() -> Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5))
                .withMinimumUploadPartSize(Long.valueOf(5L * 1024 * 1024)) // Tamaño mínimo por parte
                .withMultipartUploadThreshold(Long.valueOf(10L * 1024 * 1024)) // Umbral para multipart uploads
                .build();
        Download download = transferManager.download(bucketName, key, new File(downloadFilePath));
        try{
            download.waitForCompletion();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.log(Level.FINER, e.getMessage());
        }finally {
            transferManager.shutdownNow();
        }
    }

However, when I reach the download method, I get a 400 Bad Request error.
Does anyone know how I can efficiently retrieve the entire file from S3 without errors? I appreciate any help or suggestions.
Thank you!

To what CSV framework does those processing classes belong?
